# z-index on bootstrap sections

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two sections both `100vh` in height.

```
<section id="sectionTwo" class="section">
  <div class="container d-flex flex-column justify-content-between mh100vh">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="box">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex align-items-end">
      <div class="col-md-8 offset-4">
        <img class="btmImg" src="http://www.atfund.gatech.edu/sites/default/files/images/verticalplaceholderimage-440x680.png" alt="" />
        <img id="downImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Circle-icons-arrow-down.svg/2000px-Circle-icons-arrow-down.svg.png" class="img-fluid btnImage">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="sectionThree" class="section">
 <div class="container d-flex flex-column justify-content-between mh100vh">
 </div>
</section>
```

The first section has a couple of images on it, one of which needed to slide up and appear.  The issue I was facing was that when it was sliding up, it was on top of the second section, instead of sliding up from behind it.  As such, I gave each section a z-index

```
#sectionTwo {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
#sectionThree {
  position: relative;
  z-index:20;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

Now this has fixed the problem.  I am no however faced with another issue.  The first section has an arrow image that needs to partly sit on top of the second section.  Because of the z-index, I cant make this happen, even if I give an index higher that the second section.

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/64/) demonstrates my problem.  Is there any way to make the circle arrow image sit on top of the second section, whilst keeping the z-indexes on the sections how I have them so the other image can slide up behind?

Thanks

Comment: Does the slide effect happen only once? If so, you could you reset the z-indexes to 0 for everything after the animation has completed, and give the arrow image a z-index of say, 10.

Comment: #downImage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:50px;
  z-index: 20;
}

Comment: The animation happens on page load only.  Giving a z-index of 20 does not seem to solve it

Comment: Your image is absolutely positioned - so it's position is relative to it's parent. As you go up the element tree, you find sectionTwo at the top. which is z-index below sectionThree. Therefore, you will always see the image behind sectionThree while it is enclosed in sectionTwo. The only way around this, is to position the image relative to the parent of both sectionTwo and sectionThree. So you need to change your html. Move the image out of the sections then you can position it where you want in relation to each section.